# How to get iFrame filled with black and no src

Tags: html, css

I have an iframe on a basic HTML page.

When the page loads, the iframe contains no src and I would like it to show just black.  (Later when users click on links they will load in the iframe)

What's the best way to do make the iframe show as black on loadup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to just set the background of the iframe to black? As shown below:

```
<iframe style='background: black;' />
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vhVKb/)

Comment: Works!  I did not know you can set style on iframes.  Thanks